# Dictionary which contains words and phrases, cannot match phrases

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The user is providing a string. I have a dictionary with words and phrases, and each key in the dictionary corresponds to a word or a phrase which is associated with a spam value. The goal is to match the user input to a word/phrase of the dictionary. My code works well for words, but it is not working for phrases.

When I enter a word like `prize`, the results are as expected, but when I enter a phrase like `Produced and sent out`, it does not show any result.

Here is my code

```
#input should be : Hurry up , no fee , no cost , buy it now 
#output required : phrases should be matched and return key value as words does
from  nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize

#taking user input
string=input("enter your text: ? ")
#tokenize the worlds for comparison
#convert input into the lower case
#tokenize the input
champ_ids = (word_tokenize(string))


champ_dict ={Prize":9,  "Prizes":9,
"Produced and sent out":9,
}
#LOWER CASE ALL THE DICTIONARY VALUES


result = ""
value = 0

#iterate through dictionarty
for k,v in champ_dict.items():
    if k in champ_ids:
        result += k+" "
        value += v
print("result = ", result)
print("value = ", value)
print("status = ", status)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `champ_ids` is a list and you are comparing a string with a list, moreover, since you would like to check the input as a whole, you should use the `==` operator and not the `in`.

Just change it to:

```
for k, v in champ_dict.items():
  if k == " ".join(champ_ids):
    result += k + " "
    value += v
```

Output:

> enter your text: ? Be your own boss
>
> be your own boss
>
> result =  be your own boss
>
> value =  9
>
> status =  Normal

Comment: no its not giving output i required. i have dictionary containing words ,"get":9, "now" :9, "get it now":9 , when i enter get it now as input , it should show me value 9 , but it is showing me value of now =9 +  get it now= 9 =18   .

Comment: plz try it woith this dictionary value . 
champ_dict ={"As seen on":9, "Buy":9, "Buy direct":9,
"Buying judgments":9, "Clearance Order":9,
"Order status":9, "Orders shipped by":9,"shopper":9,
"Dig up dirt on friends ":9, "Meet singles ":9, "Score with babes":9,
"Additional Income":9, "get":9, "get it now":9}

Comment: So what is that you want to check? Do you want to check if the input as a whole match a key in your dictionary? If so, I have updated my answer to do this.

Comment: i want to check get it now should give me the value 9 , now and get should not added up again and again . phrases should be treated as phrases . but here get it now trated as get , get it now , now .

Comment: My new code should fix that then. Is trying to match the user input as a whole to a key in the dictionary. Let me know

Comment: yeah i want to check the user input against keys in dictionary . and your new updated code is working well <3